# Win32 API to QT commands - Getting window properties

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I am trying to followings to an application (running outside my application) written in QT.  How should I approach it?

```
HWND hMainWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "QT Window App");
HWND hMenu = GetMenu(hMainWnd);
char strMenuText[128];
GetMenuString(hMenu,0, strMenuText, 127, MF_BYPOSITION);
HWND hChildWnd = FindWindoEx(hMainWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Kay

Comment: The above code looks good. You should check if the returned window handle is ``nullptr`` or not. What windows properties do you want to retrieve?

Comment: Well, this code does not work for an app build with QT.  Only the first line works and the rest does not work due to QT's internal structure and processing.  I was wondering if there is a way to achieve the same result using QT or other methods.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Can you post the relevant error or crash messages?

Comment: For example, GetMenu(hMainWnd) returns 0 as well as FindWindowEx(hMainWnd, NULL,NULL,NULL).  This is because the way QT framework works is vastly different than win32 framework.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably have to use `EnumChildWindows` and find the menu-bar control yourself.

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions and all the help.  I decided to create hooks in the product code for better testability and introduce testable product design concept, which is another battle that I need to fight.  I can hack my ways through to do things, but nothing bits proper engineering approach.